# "Modified by" listed but no edit visible by mentioned user?

Tags: support, editing

It already happened a few times to me that I saw an answer pushed to the Home -> active page with the note "modified x minutes ago USER".
For example this question [What is the meaning of "chmod 666"?](https://superuser.com/questions/295591/what-is-the-meaning-of-chmod-666)
[image: Picture of question on Home page]
However when opening the question the users name is no where to be found (Ctrl +F) and there aren't multiple answers sites (1 out of 2), to navigate trough, which Ctrl + F maybe missed. So I looked at the user profiles activity, all actions and nothing is listed there too.

Now Im wondering what this means. Does it mean the user got an edit approved but it already got revoked so I was unable to see it? Or does it mean the user submitted an edit that is now under review?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was posted but was subsequently deleted because it was flagged as spam. Since there was activity on the post, it gets bumped up.

Comment: So the question was first bumped with the note: "answered x mins ago" which I must have missed, and then the answers was deleted which counts as modification. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @User025 No; The user called out was the author of the spam

Comment: That's what I meant @Ramhound , first the question must have been bumped with the note: answered x mins ago by john mikeel. I must have missed that bump and when I then went to the active questions page it was listed because the answers from john mikeel got deleted because it was spam.